# 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib==3.4.3' problem on Python 3.10

Tags: matplotlib, setup.py, python-3.10

I need help with `pip install -r matplotlib==3.4.3` on Python 3.10.

Here's my CMD output:

```
Collecting matplotlib==3.4.3
  Downloading matplotlib-3.4.3.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
  command: `'C:\Users\eob_o\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'`    

    C:\\Users\\eob_o\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-txwy9aql\\matplotlib_201a53d35123474cbeaa8a08acd5c0c5\\setup.py'"'"'     
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: `'C:\Users\eob_o\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\eob_o\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py'` build_wheel 

    'C:\Users\eob_o\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqjub6dxu'
    Complete output (200 lines):
    setup.py:63: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.21.2 may not yet support Python 3.10.
      warnings.warn(#Running from numpy source directory.

    C:\Users\eob_o\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel_qobiqz_\numpy_24f149b83cd943538729a21c1b35fa75\tools\cythonize.py:69:

    DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives from distutils.version import LooseVersion
        Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
        Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
        Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    ...
 

     BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
        matplotlib: yes [3.4.3]
            python: yes [3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC
                        v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]]
          platform: yes [win32]
             tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
    
      ----------------------------------------
    WARNING: Discarding 
    
    https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/37/197e68df384ff694f78d687a49ad39f96c67b8d75718bc61503e1676b617/matplotlib-3.4.3.tar.gz#sha256=fc4f526dfdb31c9bd6b8ca06bf9fab663ca12f3ec9cdf4496fb44bc680140318 (from https://pypi.org/simple/matplotlib/) (requires-python:>=3.7).
    
     
    Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib==3.4.3 (from versions: 0.86, 0.86.1, 0.86.2, 0.91.0, 0.91.1, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1rc1, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0b2, 2.0.0b3, 2.0.0b4, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 3.0.0rc2, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.1.0rc1, 3.1.0rc2, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.2.0rc1, 3.2.0rc3, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.3.0rc1, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.3.3, 3.3.4, 3.4.0rc1, 3.4.0rc2, 3.4.0rc3, 3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.5.0b1, 3.5.0rc1)
        ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib==3.4.3
```

Comment: matplotlib is does not yet support python 3.10

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/)

Answer (score 2):

By following the clue `setup.py:63: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.21.2 may not yet support Python 3.10.`, I decided to uninstall Python 3.10 and replace with Python 3.9. And my problem got solved!

Comment: I up-voted because you have learned (or you've learned it again...) an important fact. Not always you need the very latest version of a software! and maybe your experience, that you graciously shared, will teach something to someone else too...